# Visual Studio's brake lines in Rider

Tags: visual-studio, rider

in Visual studio when i hit enter from ternary expression `??` in constructor i get lines break like this:

[image]

But Rider doing breaking for ternaries like this:

[image]

How to set up braking lines in Rider for ternaries like it works in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't configure in the same way as VS. The wrapping of the ternary lines indents with the default Indent size (by default is set to 4). So in other word it's a fixed size and not "dynamic" like it's for VS int that situation. Maybe it's a feature you could request at [JetBrains Rider Support](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us) page.